# Akka: Events by tag and creation time

Tags: cassandra, akka, event-sourcing, lagom, akka-persistence

I have an application that uses Akka along with Cassandra for Event Sourcing. As part of an API response, I need to show the number of events of a specific type/tag (say UpdateEvent) that happened at a specific time range. Does there exists any near capability to achieve this?

I have read through "eventsByTag" query from Query Plugin and from what I understand the provide a stream of events and usage of which can have drastic impact for a client facing backend. Correct if I am wrong.

I think what I will be needing is someway to query the messages table to extract events by timeline or should I be using the stream to populate a new set of read-side table to achieve functionality.

Comment: I don't understand exactly the use case. Do you want to receive a request and in the response of that request return the number of events? do you have a separate endpoint where you want to query the number of events? are you using lagom? akka-persistence? both? if it is possible try to provide an example of the code detaililng what are the dependencies that you are using

Comment: Hello Gaston, Application is built on Lagom with multiple microservices and also has dependency for akka-persistence. Use case is: for a request from frontend return the number of "UpdateEvent"s that occurred in a given time range. Essentially a count between t1 and t2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassandra (and the schema used by Akka Persistence Cassandra) is not generally well-suited to this query, not least because it will involve a scan of the whole keyspace, so will be rather inefficient.

Accordingly, the ideal way to go will be to project the events (e.g. using Lagom's projections or Akka Projection) into a time-series database (that's one of the advantages of CQRS: the ability to use a query model that's maximally well-suited to answering the question).  If you don't happen to have a time-series database readily available, with some effort you can implement the functionality in a more general purpose database like Cassandra or a relational DB.